# jQuery date picker not working

Tags: php, codeigniter, datepicker

I'm using jQuery date picker in my php site. It's working properly, but I want to disable previous date from it. I try to do in some ways but it's not working.

My script as follow

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="<?php echo base_url("cal/jsDatePick_ltr.min.css"); ?>" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url("cal/jsDatePick.jquery.min.1.3.js"); ?>"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var today = new Date();
var y = today.getFullYear();
var m = today.getMonth();
var d=today.getDate();
window.onload = function() {
new JsDatePick({
useMode: 2,
target: "edate",
dateFormat: "%Y-%m-%d",
yearsRange:[y,9999]
});
};
</script>
```

My form as follow. I'm using codeigniter in this project:

```
<?php
$data = array(
"name" => "edate",
"id" => "edate",
"value" => "",
"class" => "form-control",
"placeholder" => "Expire Date",
"aria-describedby" => "sizing-addon1"
);
echo form_input($data);
?>
```

When I click on this texbox calender is popup successfully. but I want to disable previous dates from it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
window.onload = function() {
 new JsDatePick({
 useMode: 2,
 target: "edate",
 dateFormat: "%Y-%m-%d",
 yearsRange:[y,9999],
 minDate: 0 // Disable previous date
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this Code For That,
replace your codeigniter code with,

```
<?php
   $data = array(
       "name" => "edate",
       "id" => "edate",
       "value" => "",
       "class" => "form-control input-datepicker",
       "placeholder" => "Expire Date",
       "aria-describedby" => "sizing-addon1"
   );
echo form_input($data);
?>
```

and add This to your jquery,

```
$("#edate").datepicker({
      startDate: '1'
});
```

Comment: i try your code.but it is not working.any other suggestions?

Comment: add input-datepicker to your date picker class

Comment: how can i do that.i`m new for datepicker.